# Footer showing first when Blazor web application loads

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I have a Blazor .net core hosted application. When the site runs, the footer shows for a few seconds while the app does authorizing. Is there any way to show a loading indicator whenever there is some activity running? I am specifically referring to when the app is authorizing. I want the contents to load before showing the footer? Please see screenshot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, an "AppState" approach could be useful if I understood it correctly. It's a way to enable communication between components at any level in their hierarchy.

Let's start by defining the `AppState`. This class uses the .NET events to raise a notification when a value has changed.

```
public class AppState
{
    private Boolean _loadingIsFinished = false;

    public Boolean LoadingIsFinished
    {
        get => _loadingIsFinished;
        set
        {
            _loadingIsFinished = value;
            AppStateChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }

    public event EventHandler AppStateChanged;
}
```

The AppState is added to the dependency injection system. For Blazor WASM, it should be a singleton dependency. For Blazor Server, though, it should be a scoped one.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

    ...
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(new AppState());
    ... 
   
    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

The `Footer` component uses this state and subscribe to the change event and update a local field. This field is used to determine if the footer is displayed or not. As a good practice, the `Footer` implements the `IDisposable` to unsubscribe from the event.

```
@inject AppState _appState
@implements IDisposable

@if (_showFooter == true)
{
    <div class="footer">
        @*Footer Content*@
    </div>
}

@code {

    private Boolean _showFooter = false;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        _appState.AppStateChanged += AppStateChanged;

        _showFooter = _appState.LoadingIsFinished;
    }

    private async void AppStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        _showFooter = _appState.LoadingIsFinished;
        await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _appState.AppStateChanged -= AppStateChanged;
    }
}
```

Because the update of the AppState can happen out of band, we force the UI to update by calling `StateHasChanged`. Besides, the call is wrapped inside `InvokeAsync` to make sure it is handled correctly by the UI.

In every other component, you can inject the `AppState` and change the value of `LoadingIsFinished`. Assuming you have a `Dashboard` component, you could use the AppState like this.

```
@inject AppState _appstate

<h3>Dashboard</h3>

@code {

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();
        _appstate.LoadingIsFinished = true;
    }
}
```

**AppState coupled to authentication**

If your question is more about authentication, there is a specialized way to do it. You can inject  `AuthenticationStateProvider` into the `AppState`, introduce a new property like `IsAuthenticated` and use this property in your `Footer` component.

```
 public AppState(AuthenticationStateProvider authStateProvider)
{
    _authStateProvider = authStateProvider;
    _authStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged += HandleAuthStateChanged;
}

private async void HandleAuthStateChanged(Task<AuthenticationState> task)
{
    var state = await task;
    IsAuthentication = state.User != null && state.User.Claims.Any();
}

public void Dispose()
{
    _authStateProvider.AuthenticationStateChanged -= HandleAuthStateChanged;
}

public event EventHandler AppStateChanged;

private Boolean _isAuthenticated = false;
public Boolean IsAuthenticated
{
    get => _isAuthenticated;
    set
    {
        _isAuthenticated = value;
        AppStateChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
```

This is a fundamental version of an "AppState". However, there are frameworks like [Fluxor](https://github.com/mrpmorris/Fluxor) for all these state transitions, or you could use a more decoupled way like a message bus for components, called [ComponentBus](https://github.com/cpear/BlazorComponentBus).

Comment: Thank you for your very detailed and prompt response !  I have decided to switch to Blazor server where I have a dreamboat experience. Personally, I don't think the MS team have got the plumbing of a.net core hosted Wasm sorted yet. I have zero issues working with the server. We really should not have to go to such lengths to manage what is a simple footer in an application. Stand alone .net core did not have these issues so this is, in essence a backwards step.