# How to make a razor component re-render from another razor component

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, blazor

I can't seem to make a razor component re-render from actions taken from another component. For instance:

say we have a component base 'ComponentVariables' where a variable 'buttonClickCount' is defined to keep track of how many times a button is clicked, as well as the method to increment the variable.

#### ComponentVariables.cs

```
sing Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

namespace WebApplication2.Components
{
    public class ComponentVariables : ComponentBase
    {
        [Parameter]
        public int buttonClickCount { get; set; }

        public ComponentVariables() { }

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            buttonClickCount = 0;
        }

        public void clickCounter()
        {
            buttonClickCount++;
            StateHasChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Then its inherited by all components in _Imports.razor with `@inherits ComponentVariables`

The home component has the following code

#### Home.razor

```
<div class="row">
    <strong>@buttonClickCount</strong>
    <Clicker/>
</div>
```

and the button is created in the Clicker.razor component. along with an onclick that references the method in the component base. and a div containing the count (also from the component base).

#### Clicker.razor

```
<div>
    <button @onclick="clickCounter">Click Me</button>
</div>

<div>@buttonClickCount</div>

@code
{
}
```

As it is right now, both home.razor and clicker.razor are using the same variable in ComponentVariables.cs to display a value. however, when i click, only the Clicker component gets rerendered. i.e. home always displays 0 while clicker increases as you click.

Any help with this would be very appreciated.

Comment: You used inheritance. So, it might seem, that you manipulate the same variable because they have the name, but in fact, they are all unique instances with unique values. 
Maybe, you can describe what you want to achieve with this approach?

Comment: i started to use the debugger more and noticed that the base was called for each razor component. which means that you're correct i suspect.

so in this case how would i use reference the same variable across all components and make them all dynamically change with updates to said variable?

Comment: There are three ways to handle it. Based on your description, I would recommend an AppState. I have written an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896236/footer-showing-first-when-blazor-web-application-loads). Alternatively you can have a look at [this post](https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/)

Comment: Thanks so much! i just read through both links. they look very helpful, especially the appstate one. 
follow up question though, would it then be possible to limit those the re-render to specific components based on the variable changed? cause that's the most important part for my situation.

Comment: @VictoryObot, what about events or delegates? `<Clicker onClick="InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)" />`

Comment: @VictoryObot. The component that received the event and updates any of their fields/property, call after updating them ```InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)```. There is your limit. However, if the component has many child components, they will go through the same process to decide if a rerender is needed. But this is more a question of component design. Usually, it isn't a performance problem and I'd suggest starting paying attention when you think you have a performance problem.

Comment: @daniherrera that really didnt help too much to be honest

Comment: @Justthebenno yeah thanks a lot. what i'm doing now is having an Action for each variable declared in the appstate where i know a re-render would be needed somewhere. and then just having the relevant components watch that Action.

Comment: @VictoryObot, take a look https://blazorrepl.com/repl/cFkPGrFQ45UDeH9320

Comment: @daniherrera oh i see. thanks for this. i think for my issue i'd prefer to use appstate logic but this is also pretty nifty. thanks so much !

Comment: @Justthebenno's comment really should just be the answer. Also this is a perfect example of where an MVVM framework for Blazor would come in handy.

Comment: @VictoryObot I've created an answer based on our conversation and added some other thoughts that might be helpful for you and others

Comment: i'll mark that correct for sure.  and @PeterMoore i'll look into the MVVM framework as well!

Comment: @VictoryObot sorry to misguide you - there is no MVVM framework for Blazor that I know of. I was just wishing there were. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used inheritance. So, it might seem that you manipulate the same variable because they have the name, but in fact, they are all unique instances with unique values.

If you want to exchange a value between different components, there are three ways to do it. [This blog post](https://chrissainty.com/3-ways-to-communicate-between-components-in-blazor/) describe them. Based on your description, I'd recommend an *AppState* approach. I've written an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65896236/footer-showing-first-when-blazor-web-application-loads).

I've copied the relevant parts for my previous answer and add some new thoughts.

Let's start by defining the `AppState`. This class uses the .NET events or delegates to raise a notification when a value has changed.

```
public class AppState
{
    private Int32 _clickCounter = 0;

    public Int32 ClickCounter
    {
        get => _clickCounter;
        set
        {
            _clickCounter = value;
            AppStateChanged?.Invoke(nameof(ClickCounter), this);
        }
    }

    public event AppStateChangedHandler AppStateChanged;
}
```

The handler `public delegate void AppStateChangedHandler(String propertyName, AppState state);`. The change handler includes the object itself and the `propertyName`, that has changed. This can be used by components subscribing to the event to filter if the change is relevant.

The AppState is added to the dependency injection system. For Blazor WASM, it should be a singleton dependency. For Blazor Server, though, it should be a scoped one.

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");

    ...
    builder.Services.AddSingleton(new AppState());
    ... 
   
    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}
```

The `Counter` component from the default template should be an example of using the AppState to propagate a change. This component is changed slightly.

```
@page "/Counter"
@inject AppState appState

<h1>Counter</h1>

<p>Current count: @appState.ClickCounter</p>

<button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="IncrementCount">Click me</button>

@code {

    private void IncrementCount()
    {
        appState.ClickCounter++;
    }
}
```

Instead of incrementing (and reading) a local variable, the corresponding property from the AppState is used.

To simplify the subscription to the change event and reduce the boilerplate in each component, we create an abstract base called `AppStateAwareComponentBase`. This should be a normal .cs file.

```
public abstract class AppStateAwareComponentBase : ComponentBase, IDisposable
{
    [Inject]
    protected AppState AppState { get; private set; }

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        base.OnInitialized();

        AppState.AppStateChanged += AppStateChanged;
    }

    protected abstract Boolean HandleAppStateChanged(String propertyName, AppState state);

    private async void AppStateChanged(String propertyName, AppState state)
    {
        Boolean changesOccured = HandleAppStateChanged(propertyName, state);
        if (changesOccured == true)
        {
            await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        AppState.AppStateChanged -= AppStateChanged;
    }
}
```

This class is subscribed to change event but doesn't know how to handle it exactly. Hence, it has an abstract method called `HandleAppStateChanged` that need to be implemented in the concrete classes later. This class determines if a layout change is a subsequent result. The child calls returns `true` if a layout update is needed. The parent class (`AppStateAwareComponentBase`) initiate an layout update via invoking `InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged)`.

If  The `AppState` is injected via `[Inject]` and the implementation of `IDisposable` guarantee that the subscription to the delegate is removed when the component is removed from the tree.

I've created a `CounterHeader` component, as a class inherits from AppStateAwareComponentBase

```
@inherits AppStateAwareComponentBase

<span>Current App Global Counter: @_counter </span>

@code{

   private Int32 _counter = 0;

   protected override Boolean HandleAppStateChanged(String propertyName, AppState state)
   {
       if(propertyName != nameof(AppState.ClickCounter)) {
           return false;
       }
       
       _counter = state.ClickCounter;
       return true;
   }
}
```

[Here is a link to the corresponding repository](https://github.com/just-the-benno/AppStateAwareComponents).

**Additional Thoughts**

This is a fundamental version of an "AppState". However, there are frameworks like [Fluxor](https://github.com/mrpmorris/Fluxor) for all these state transitions, or you could use a more decoupled way like a message bus for components, called [ComponentBus](https://github.com/cpear/BlazorComponentBus).

There can be multiple "states" per application, like `ShoopingCardState`, `UserState` etc., to split it into different smaller parts.

Comment: Can't believe I forgot to say thanks. So, thank you very much fr